# Regression variable conversion

Tags: regression, self-study, variance, covariance, r-squared

There is a question that I cannot solve. They may be solved by variance and covariance but I couldn't. So I thought there should be another way to solve.

Question:
A researcher has a sample of 43 observations on a dependent variable, Y, and two potential explanatory variables, X and Z. He defines two further variables V and W as the sum of X and Z and the difference between them:

\begin{align}
V_i &= X_i + Z_i  \\
W_i &= X_i - Z_i
\end{align}

He fits the following four regressions:

```
(1) A regression of Y on X and Z
(2) A regression of Y on V and W
(3) A regression of Y on V
(4) A regression of Y on Z and V
```

The table shows the regression results (standard errors in parentheses; RSS = residual sum of squares; there was an intercept, not shown, in each regression).

```
(1) Y = 0.60 X + 0.80 Z, R^2=0.60, RSS=200
       (0.04)   (0.04)
(2) Y =    A V +    B W, R^2=   E, RSS=  F
       (   B)   (   D)
(3) Y = 0.72 V           R^2=   G, RSS=220
       (0.02)
(4) Y =    H V +    J W, R^2=   L, RSS=  M
       (   I)   (   K)
```

X,Z,V and W are variables. A,B,C,D,E,G,H,I,J,K,L and M are numbers to calculate.

How these numbers can be calculated?

Edit: I think, A,C,H and J can be found by variance formulas. For ex,

\begin{align}
0.6 &= {\rm Cov}(X,Y)/{\rm Var}(X)  \newline
0.8 &= {\rm Cov}(Z,Y)/{\rm Var}(Z)  \newline
\  \\
    &\text{By using them:}  \newline
\  \\
0.72 &= {\rm Cov}(V,Y)/{\rm Var}(V)  \newline
     &= ({\rm Cov}(X,Y) + {\rm Cov}(Z,Y)) / ({\rm Var}(X) + {\rm Var}(Z) + 2{\rm Cov}(X,Z))
\end{align}

${\rm Var}(X)$ and ${\rm Var}(Z)$ may be calculated by squaring standard errors. So, ${\rm Var}(X) = {\rm Var}(Z) = (0.04)^2 = 0.0016$, but I cannot go on.

Comment: We welcome questions like this, but we treat them differently. Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you've done thus far, what you understand, & where you're stuck; we'll provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Ah, sorry and also thanks for your help. I tried to add something but it looks they dont let me to go more. Anyway, I'm trying to reach to result.